# How to get the correct output for my program (String Formatting)?

Tags: java, printing, string-formatting

This question is a bit badly worded (I know), but I don't know the exact name of what I am looking for.

I have a HashMap and I am printing the keys and values of the HashMap.
the desired output is this one:

[image: desired output :)]

what I am actually getting is this:

[image: actual output :(]

My current code is so:

```
System.out.println("\n\nTom Hanks' co-stars are");
    costarMovieMap.forEach((k, v)-> System.out.printf("\t%s\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t in \t\t\t\t\t\t\t%s\n", k, v));
```

Monstrous am I right?
My guess is that to get the desired output I have to specify for the `%s` to begin at a certain line space or something. I am not quite sure. Any Ideas/suggestions as to what I can do?

ps: Uhh funny I just realized I caught a bug on the screenshot. Tom Hanks can't be his own co-star now can he :).

Comment: You're looking for the *`width`* component of a Java format specifier string, which you can use instead of all of those `\t` chars. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html and look for `Format String Syntax`. Do what it says to do for using `width`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are outputting a string, you can specify the width as part of your format.  This will pad the string with spaces until the required width is met.

Now, I'm not going to count spaces, but it might look like this:

```
System.out.println("\n\nTom Hanks' co-stars are");
    costarMovieMap.forEach((k, v)-> System.out.printf("\t%20s in     %s\n", k, v));
```

PS With enough creative video editing, yes, Tom Hanks can be his own co-star.

Comment: Haha, yeah you're right, With enough creative video editing much is possible. 
Thanks for the solution it's almost what I am looking for, although the width of 20 gets applied to the first word and that's not the correct output. It does gide me in the right direction though. thanks.

Comment: No worries.  Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer so that it's easier for others to benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, this will print similar to your expected result.

```
costarMovieMap.forEach((k, v)-> System.out.printf("%1$-15s %2$-8s  %s \n", k, "in", v));
```

> The optional argument_index is a
>   decimal integer indicating the
>   position of the argument in the
>   argument list. The first argument is
>   referenced by "1$", the second by
>   "2$", etc.
>
> The optional flags is a set of
>   characters that modify the output
>   format. The set of valid flags depends
>   on the conversion.
>
> The optional width is a decimal integer indicating the minimum
>   number of characters to be written to
>   the output.
>
> The optional precision is a
>   non-negative decimal integer usually
>   used to restrict the number of
>   characters. The specific behavior
>   depends on the conversion.
>
> The required conversion is a
>   character indicating how the argument
>   should be formatted. The set of valid
>   conversions for a given argument
>   depends on the argument's data type.

`%1$` refers to the first substitution. In this case the key. you are saying there has to be a minimum of 15 characters if not it will be padded.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html